# Angular router navigation triggers POPSTATE IMPERATIVE and HASHCHANGE

Tags: angular, triggers, navigation, router

Router in angular has navigationstart and navigationend properties which in turn have navigation trigger : 1. **popstate** -> when url is hit directly from the browser.
2. **imperative** -> when routing is done within in the application as a result of some action like button click. 
3. **hashchange** -> **When does a hashchange trigger occurs** ? When I do a popstate trigger directly from browser, the url gets hit again with a hashChange trigger not sure why ? Any thoughts on this